# How to bind input field to editfor model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following javascript and input fields within my model.

```
script type="text/javascript">

        function sum() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('money1').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('money2').value;
            var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('money3').value;
            var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtThirdNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('Total').value = result;
            }
        }
    </script>

<div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total, "Total", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                            <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                <input type="text" id="Total" name="Total" />
                                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total)*@
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.money1, "money1", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                            <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money1)*@
                                <input type="text" id="money1" onkeyup="sum();" name="money1" />
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.money1)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.money2, "money2", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                            <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money2)*@
                                <input type="text" id="money2" onkeyup="sum();" name="money2" />
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.money2)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.money3, "money3", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                            <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money3)*@
                                <input type="text" id="money3" onkeyup="sum();" name="money3" />
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.money3)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This all works fine. When I type a value into the 3 money fields the resulting value appears in the Total field. Within MVC if I click on the details view it shows all four values, however if I click on the edit view all four fields are blank. Question is how do I get the values to appear and remain in edit mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for starters your model-bound input fields are commented out:

```
@*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money1)*@
```

In order to get those to work you'd need to un-comment them.

You *could* just manually populate your markup with the model values, something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="money1" onkeyup="sum();" name="money1" value="@model.money1" />
```

That should pre-populate that `input` with the model's `money1` value.  Though you're assuming the responsibility of manually implementing anything else that the built-in HTML helpers would provide for you.  Unless there's a compelling reason not to use `Html.EditorFor()` I imagine that would be the better option.

Comment: Thanks David, your recommendation worked great for money1,2,3! Although the Total value isn't redisplayed like the other three values. The reasoning behind the commenting out of @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.money1)*@ was because I couldn't get the JavaScript to work with it but it worked fine by using <input>.

Comment: @Scanner: Does the model *have* a total value field? I imagine it should, and you'd display its value exactly the same way. (Though I wouldn't bind an editor to it, since it's a calculated value. It probably shouldn't be in a form element, just displayed in the markup.) As for the JavaScript "not working" with the editors, that sounds like something for a different question entirely. There's nothing special about the markup emitted by those editors, JavaScript can interact with it like any other markup.

Comment: I added a value attribute into the Total field (<input type="text" id="ContractualWeekly" name="WeeklyRatesPayable" value="@Model.ContractualWeekly" />) just the same as money 1, 2, 3 and the value displays as it should but when I click on edit again its value has disappeared. I'm pretty new to this so thats why I was having a hard time getting the editors and Javascript to co-operate but as you say thats for a different time.

Comment: @Scanner: Well where does that value come from? Does the model even *have* it at all? If it's being calculated by JavaScript and not by server-side code then you can always re-calculate it by just executing that JavaScript. I really don't see why the total value needs to be an input field, it shouldn't be an editable value on the model. If anything it would be a read-only property (only a getter, no setter) which just returns the total of the other fields.

Comment: The client who I'm working for requested the application to be create, edit, details format and wants control over editting to the extent that when the click edit all 4 fields are populated. Is it that because money 1, 2, 3 are added so that Total achieves its value that that is the reason why no value displays for Total when edit is clicked?

Comment: @Scanner: So the client wants to be able to *edit* the total? What if they change it to be different than the actual calculated total? That seems pretty silly. As for why no value displays, it sounds like the model doesn't *have* the value. According to the code in the question, the value is calculated by JavaScript. So just invoke that JavaScript logic to calculate it. Call `sum()` when the edit page loads. This would of course overwrite any existing value pre-populated by the model. But you really seem to be confusing where this logic exists and how the value is tracked.

Comment: They want to be able to adjust money 1, 2, 3 which they can do but they want to see all 4 values including Totals value when the click the edit link. As I said I am new to this and just trying to figure it all out, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Scanner: If they just want to *see* the total then it doesn't need to be in an `input` field.  If the model has some kind of `.Total` property (whatever you're calling it) then you can just display that value, likely with some kind of HTML markup around it: `<span id="calculatedTotal">@model.Total</span>`.  The same JavaScript can update the value client-side by just changing the jQuery selector and editing the text instead of the value.  The value can be calculated server-side in the model (in the `.Total` property itself) with the same logic.

Comment: David I've made a mistake which I just spotted, I originally had <input type="text" id="ContractualWeekly" name="WeeklyRatesPayable" value="@Model.ContractualWeekly" />, name has the wrong "name" placed into it. When I corrected it so that name="ContracutalWeekly" it works exactly as I want. Thanks for your help and patience, Happy New Year!